# Stuck trying to build UE for iOS on Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unreal-engine5, apple-silicon

I am trying to build an AR game for iOS, using a custom build of Unreal Engine 5.1.1, on an Apple Silicon (M1 Max) Macbook Pro.

(I have to use a [custom branch of UE5](https://github.com/JFrit/UnrealEngine/tree/5.1-ARSceneCapture-Fix) because there is a problem with using AR and Scene Capture.)

Everything was going fine until I (stupidly) let my iPhone 14 update itself to iOS 17.

Now I cannot build for it anymore, because 17 requires using Xcode 15. But when I build our project in Xcode 15, for packaging in UE, it fails with some low level assembly/machine language instruction.

It works fine with Xcode 14, but I cannot install to my phone for testing. And obviously I cannot downgrade my phone.

Can anyone shed any light here?